# Unable to Get Paragraph InputType to Display Any Text In Azure B2C IEF

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am having some trouble using the Paragraph UserInput Type available to Azure B2C IEF. I would like to use the Paragraph element because it would make localization a lot easier. However, no matter what I have tried, I am unable to get the Paragraph element to display any text.

I have tried to follow the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#paragraph and I have also contacted the B2C Team via GitHub and was recommended I assign default values.

### ClaimType

```
<ClaimType Id="UserExistsErrorMessage">
    <DisplayName>Error Message</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

In my technical profile I am assigning a default value

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserExistsErrorMessage" DefaultValue="Test">
```

I am expecting the paragraph to display the text that I have assigned. Instead all I am getting is a blank < p>< /p> HTML tags when reviewing the source during testing.

Answer (score 2):

To set the value of Paragraph UserInputType, please set default value using input claim.

```
<InputClaims>
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserExistsErrorMessage" DefaultValue="Test"/>
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserExistsErrorMessage"/>
</OutputClaims>
```

Comment: Can you localize the default value string with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the **Enumeration** value that must be set to the display value:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="UserExistsErrorMessage">
  <DisplayName>Error Message</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Enumeration Text="Test" Value="This is a test message." />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your response. I have tried using the example that the documentation provided that also listed the Enumerations but was unable to get it to display anything. Can you provide an example? Are you suggesting that the outputclaim value should equal the 'Text' of the enumeration?

Comment: Update. I have tried every permutation that I can possibly come up with and am still unable to display any text in a Paragraph claim.